# Backbone item view needs to put HTML into tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, backbone.js

I'm using Backbone and Bootstrap.  My target here is to end with a dynamically generated list of notes, with the note title in a vertically stacked tab list on the left and the note content in tab-pane on the right.

Here is some quick HTML to demonstrate:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked">
            <li><a href="#note1" data-toggle="tab">Note 1 Title</a></li>
            <li><a href="#note2" data-toggle="tab">Note 2 Title</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane" id="note1">Here is note 1's content</div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="note2">Here is note 2's content</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Each Note is a Backbone Model.  I have a Notes view, responsible for owning the collection's HTML content seen above, and a Note view, responsible for rendering each Note model.
The problem is that each Note model's required output is made of two 'sections' of HTML, in different parts (title and content) of the DOM owned by Notes View.

My question is, how do you work it such that the render() method on the Note View is able to return the necessary HTML to poke into both the titles and content?

It doesn't feel like it can return both items in one return value, and maybe I'll need to return an array with two elements 'title' html and 'content' html.  Is this the canonical best way of approaching this issue in Backbone?

Suggestions for further reading gratefully received.

Comment: One view for the whole `.row`, this can also manage the `ul.nav-tabs` since the `<li>` tabs are part of the tabbed interface rather than part of the panel internals. Then subviews for the `.tab-pane`s.

Comment: I did think of this - my only hesitation was if I then went on to add additional events to the title tab (such as a delete), then this will be picked up in the Notes View (whole .row view) rather than the Note View.  Not insurmountable at all, but it does feel to me that Note specific event should be caught by the Note specific view.

Comment: But you can view delete as a message to the collection so having the collection-view handle it is perfectly natural.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would reduce complexity to have this whole thing rendered using a single View (your "NotesView") rather than using sub-views. You can associate each note element with a data-id or data-cid attribute so that you can grab the appropriate model in an event handler from your collection when something of interest happens (delete, etc). Then you can just do the iteration of the Notes collection in your template.

Alternatively, there's no need to try and force the Note Model to be 1 to 1 with a View. If I wanted to have separate views for the html you provided, I'd have something like a 'NoteTitleView' and a 'NoteContentView' that both accept a NoteModel in the options.

Comment: I played around with different options here for a while.  The two separate views didn't work out at all, as it muddled the save process when making updates.  The single view that didn't pass back $el but rather an array of HTML with 'title' and 'content' elements was better, but defeated the point.  The only method that made sense was to dispense with the single model view and render at the collection level.  It did make the event handling more clunky than I would have liked, but logically it made sense.  Thanks for taking the time to comment.